# Create object instance name dynamically

Tags: php, api, object, analytics

I have an array of weeks that is created dynamically elsewhere (here's the print_r dump):

```
  array:28 [▼
  “week1” => “2018-03-01”
  “week2” => “2018-03-08”
  “week3” => “2018-03-15”
  “week4” => “2018-03-22”
  “week5” => “2018-03-29”
  “week6” => “2018-04-05”
  “week7” => “2018-04-12”
  “week8” => “2018-04-19”
  “week9” => “2018-04-26”
  “week10” => “2018-05-03”
  “week11” => “2018-05-10”
  “week12” => “2018-05-17”
  “week13” => “2018-05-24”
  “week14” => “2018-05-31”
  “week15” => “2018-06-07”
  “week16” => “2018-06-14”
  “week17” => “2018-06-21”
  “week18” => “2018-06-28”
  “week19” => “2018-07-05”
  “week20” => “2018-07-12”
  “week21” => “2018-07-19”
  “week22” => “2018-07-26”
  “week23” => “2018-08-02”
  “week24” => “2018-08-09”
  “week25” => “2018-08-16”
  “week26” => “2018-08-23”
  “week27” => “2018-08-30”
  “week28” => “2018-09-06”
]
```

For each of these weeks, I would like to create an instance of the Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange object so that I can query multiple date ranges in the same batch call.

However, according to the Google Analytics Reporting API V4, I have to create instances with different names:

[Samples  |  Analytics Reporting API v4       |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)

Specifically:

```
$march = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$march->setStartDate(“2015-03-01”);
$march->setEndDate(“2015-03-31”);

$January = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$January->setStartDate(“2015-01-01”);
$January->setEndDate(“2015-01-31”);
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out if it’s possible to loop through the weeks array to create the multiple instances (with different names) dynamically. Here’s my method:

```
private function get_timeline_report($analytics, $campaign_start_date, $dates, $expression=null, $alias=null, $filter=null, User $user)
{
    $dates = (array_values($dates));

    foreach ($dates as $key => $value)
    {
        // todo - need to get date and give it a name (week1 etc - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.newx)
        // Create the DateRange object.
        $date_ranges[$key] = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $date_ranges[$key]->setStartDate($campaign_start_date);
        $date_ranges[$key]->setEndDate($value);
    }

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression($expression);
    $sessions->setAlias($alias);

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($user->ga_view_id);
    $request->setDateRanges($date_ranges);
    $request->setMetrics($sessions);
    $request->setFiltersExpression($filter);

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests(array($request));

    return $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);
}
```

Is it possible to create instance names dynamically, and if yes, how? The current code returns this Google Service Exception:

```
(1/1) Google_Service_Exception
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week1\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week2\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week3\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week4\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week5\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week6\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week7\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week8\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week9\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week10\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week11\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week12\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week13\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week14\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week15\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week16\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week17\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week18\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week19\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week20\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week21\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week22\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week23\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week24\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week25\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week26\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week27\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week28\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week1\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week2\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week3\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week4\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week5\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week6\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week7\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week8\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week9\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week10\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week11\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week12\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week13\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week14\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week15\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week16\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week17\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week18\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week19\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week20\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week21\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week22\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week23\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week24\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week25\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week26\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week27\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"week28\" at 'report_requests[0].date_ranges[0]': Cannot find field.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

Comment: These quotes `“` will not work. Use a text editor rather than a word processor to edit code

Comment: Thanks, that's a print_r dump.

Comment: FWIW, it's entirely meaningless to use names such as `$march` or `$January` here. The important thing is that you create a new instance of `new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange`. What variable name you assign that to is completely irrelevant. You don't need to create those variable names dynamically, you should probably just keep those object instances in an array. The error you get does not stem from your use of variable names, but from some incorrect data you send to the API. What specifically the right data is I don't know though.

Comment: @deceze please edit the question in order to make the answers more relevant as it just leads to bad practices answers...

Comment: @deceze as I said in my really bad answer date_ranges array must only have numerical index.The issue come from there as the error message show and the google example too...

Comment: @Elementary There's no need to edit the question. You just need to change your answer to tell OP what the actual problem is, how to solve it, and why dynamic variable names have nothing to do with it.

Comment: will you then upvote my answer?

Comment: @Elementary If it's a good answer, sure.

Comment: @deceze done......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked the bad question as your error doesn't actually come from the name of your object instance.
In the google sample on multiple date range we can notice :

```
 $request->setDateRanges(array($march, $january));
```

As you may see yourself ,this array is not at all associative.So we can conclude that Google Api don't use at all your instances names but only the dateRange instances  themselves.So your first code may work fine if instead of :

```
foreach ($dates as $key => $value)
    {
        // Create the DateRange object.
        $date_ranges[$key] = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $date_ranges[$key]->setStartDate($campaign_start_date);
        $date_ranges[$key]->setEndDate($value);
    }
```

you use something like:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($dates as $key => $value)
{
    // Create the DateRange object.
    $date_ranges[$i] = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $date_ranges[$i]->setStartDate($campaign_start_date);
    $date_ranges[$i]->setEndDate($value);
    $i++;
}
unset($i,$key,$value);
```